# Can we add more than one subviews to a window at the same time in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, window, subview, addsubview

Is it possible to add more than 1 subviews to a given window. Eg. `[window addsubview: subview1] [window addsubview: subview2]` where one of the views is UIViewController. 
I tried doing it but the UIViewController view overrides the other subview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add multiple subviews to `UIWindow`.

For your problem check the frames of the views you add - probably your viewController's view is fullscreen and another view is just under it

Answer (score 3):

Make sure both the views do not have the same size, so they do not overlap each other. Try changing one view's x and y location and background colour to something that stands out from the other one to see what I mean.

A quick look at the [UIWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html) docs would have revealed it inherited from UIView, to which you can add an arbitrary number of subviews.

Comment: How can I change a view x and y location ?

Comment: It's pretty simple, actually. It's most probably frame.origin.x, and frame.origin.y. Check out the CGRect, CGSize and CGPoint (I believe that's what they're called) class definitions!